# Populate multiple tables using the same dataframe

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have an HTML template which has 3 tables. There is a single backend Dataframe and each of the 3 tables need to be populated with a filtered segment of the dataframe.

Eg:

HTML Template:

Table 1
Table 2
Table 3

[image: Dataframe]

Thereby all the A company values get populated in table 1, B in table 2 and C in table 3.

Would I be able to filter them in my HTML script or would it be better to filter and create the filtered dataframes and pass them to the HTML template.

Im using render_templates in flask

Comment: Filtering them in Python code will be more clear for you. You can do it inside html with some Jinja filtering or if statement, but i would definitely go with th first option.

Comment: How would I associate the different dataframes with the different table IDs then?

Comment: I added an answer, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create 3 different dataframes before rendering the html, like below:

```
dfA=df[df.Company=='A']
dfB=df[df.Company=='B']
dfC=df[df.Company=='C']
```

add all of them in the context while rendering, for example

```
return render_template('yourhtml.html', dfA=dfA, dfB=dfB, dfC=dfC)
```

and inside the html, you will add 3 different tables, by looping in dfA, dfB,dfC seperately